# How to change the text "like" in facebook plug-in like button into a custom text?

Tags: facebook, plugins, facebook-like, facebook-social-plugins

**How to change the text "like" in facebook plug-in like button into a custom text?**

Answer (score 3):

Edit: you can't access it with JS unless you're a facebook.com domain.

You can choose from a preset verb list [through FB's API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) (right now it's either "like" or "recommend").

Comment: thanks for the response sombe but i've already tried that code and that wont work coz facebook like is inside iframe

Comment: I believe iframe content can only be changed if accessed from the same domain (so if you're not FB or a FB app it's a problem). How about designing your own button?

Comment: ok i think ill just design my own button then just overlaps it via CSS?

Comment: Right, you could set iframe's opacity to 0 and display a button behind it. I don't think FB has a url you can href to for *like* functionality.

Comment: It should be noted that this is against Facebook policy and they may take actions against you if the find out you are altering the appearance of the "like" button.